# Chrome refuses to let me connect to local test web server using HTTP

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I develop a number of web apps. At least two of them run on localhost:8080 (one at a time, obviously). I used to be able to connect to them both using http://localhost:8080.

I was asked to make one of them more secure, and added Strict-Transport-Security and various other security headers to the code.

Now I am unable to use the other one via http - Chrome gives me "This site can’t provide a secure connection".

How can i reset Chrome so it doesn't always insist that site uses https?

I have Googled, and can find advice to "Clear SSL state" in Windows, but the instructions seem to be old, and do not work in Windows 10.

Comment: What webserver, IDE, code language(s), etc. are you using? What URL/port  do you use for the other site?  Are you using a URL redirect or a URL rewriter?

Comment: The server is written in C#, visual studio 2019. Both sites are on localhost, same port (but it makes no difference if I change the port). No redirects or rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit) I misread. Chrome doesn't know the sites are different on localhost. To the browser they are the same site with inconsistent security.  If the Secure site is using port 80, all traffic on port 80 will need to be configured for SSL. The SSL enabled site should be bound to https using port 443 instead of 80 on the web server config. How that's done depends on what server you use.

Comment: I am aware that testing the secure site using localhost as the url was a mistake, as I can no longer use localhost for non secure sites. I hoped that there was a way (short of reformatting my disk and reinstalling Windows, perhaps using a different Google account as well) of telling Chrome (or Windows?) to forget the security information it has stored about localhost, and let me get back to normal. Then I could add a new name in the hosts file, and stick to that for testing the secure one.

Comment: Oh, and neither test site used ports 80 or 443 (they are busy doing real stuff)

Comment: All websites are bound to some port. it's not a choice like skipping leg day at the gym...If you are using the default installation of vs2019, you're running on IIS and it has bindings. If you've implemented your security in a nonstandard way, you are going to have non-standard results. VS sets up a config for your solution and places http traffic on localhost:49153.  I can't run both, to we redirect  ssl sites to https but ignore localhost.  for testing the ssl itself we use a dev server.

Comment: You are confusing me with someone who is using IIS. This is a plain Web server, nothing to do with IIS.